# How to add a sum column with respect to a group by

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table1 :

```
ZP      age      Sexe    Count
A       40       0       5
A       40       1       3
C       55       1       2
```

And i want to add a column wich sum the count column by grouping the first two variables :

```
ZP      age      Sexe    Count   Sum 
A       40       0       5       8
A       40       1       3       8
C       55       1       2       2
```

this is what i do :

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT zp, age, SUM(count) FROM table1 GROUP BY zp, age
```

then :

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
```

But i have a feeling this is a sloppy way to do it. Do you know any better ways ? For example with no intermediates tables.

edit : i am using SQL through a proc sql in SAS

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? (The second statement is invalid anyway: you can't join to the table you are creating with that statement)

Comment: I am using sql through SAS. I think it allows only standard SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if there is a method for a single `select` statement but below will work without multiple `create table` statements:

```
data have;
    length ZP $3 age 3 Sexe $3 Count 3;
    input ZP $ age Sexe $ Count;
    datalines;
    A       40       0       5
    A       40       1       3
    C       55       1       2
    ;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    create table WANT as
    select a.*, b.SUM 
    from
        (select * from HAVE) a,
        (select ZP,sum(COUNT) as SUM from HAVE group by ZP) b
    where a.ZP = b.ZP;
quit;
```

Comment: there is no need for distinct in your last select, group by ZP ensures distinct ZP

Comment: Good catch @kristof, thanks. Updated the code above.

Answer (score 1):

PROC SQL does not support enhanced SQL features like PARTITION.

But it looks like you want to include summarized data and detail rows at the same time?  If that is the question then PROC SQL will do that for you automatically.  If you include in your list of variables to select variables that are neither  group by variables or summary statistics then SAS will automatically add in the needed re-joining of the summary statistics to the detail rows to produce the table you want.

```
proc sql;
  SELECT zp, age, sexe, count, SUM(count)
    FROM table1
    group by zp, age
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM as follows with standard SQL:2003 syntax (I don't know if SAS accepts it):

```
SELECT zp, age, sexe, count, SUM(count) OVER (PARTITION BY zp, age)
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
    input ZP $ age Sexe Count;
    datalines;
    A 40 0 5
    A 40 1 3
    C 55 1 2
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as select 
        *, sum(count) as sum
        from have
        group by zp, age;
quit;
```